# G ++ can not pass the parameters in using the C ++ 11 process library under Windows?

Tags: c++11

When using G ++, Windows11 wants to use the lower thread library.But I found the problem.When using it, it will not report an error when the parameters are not passed, but an error occurs after the passing parameters.

Click to enter the definition of the definition of the header file definition is clearly correct.

The specific error is shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJLVI.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00rTI.png)

I have tried various libraries after C ++ 11 and tried to change the updated G ++ compiler, but they all failed.

I hope that there can be a big brother to answer this question.

Can solve why this problem occurs

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code as image. Edit your question and post the code as text (preferably using markup). The same considers the error message: do not post it as image.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask